# setting an input field using xpath

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have a form such as this:

[image]

I am trying to set the input field value to a postal code value "M3C1B4" and then I would like to click the button.

Although I can click the button I am unable to set the value of the input field.

I've tried the following code with no success:

```
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].value = "M3C1B4";', driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="shippingBox-update"]//input'))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="shippingBox-update"]//input').send_keys('M3C1B4')
```

Clicking the button works using this code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="shippingBox-update"]//button').click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `_` instead of `-` in `"shippingBox_update"`. Should be

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="shippingBox-update"]//input').send_keys('M3C1B4')
```

By the way, why don't you use the `<input>` class?

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("PC_change_input").send_keys('M3C1B4')
driver.find_element_by_class_name("button-submit").click()
```

Comment: Actually you are right I did use a _ instead of a -. However, it still doesn't work.

Comment: I got it to work actually. Because of your tip, I fixed my error and then I saw that the textbox was being interacted with but it was already populated with a default value which had to be cleared. When I cleared it, the box is now being populated properly!

Comment: you're right I should just use the input class but I'll optimize the code at a later time. Right now just want to quickly prototype.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the trouble. I got it to work. Apart from the error where I had _ instead of - that was pointed out by "guy", there was another problem.

The box was populated by a default value that had to be cleared first because the box only allowed for 6 values.

This did the trick:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="shippingBox-update"]//input').clear()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="shippingBox-update"]//input').send_keys('M3C1B6')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="shippingBox-update"]//button').click()
```